# How to convert Html code to design

Tags: c#, html, .net

`enter code here`i am having the raw html data as like this in **string variable**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Name to check</p>
<input type="text" name="t_name" align="left" size="80" maxlength="80">
<p>Supporting details - DOB, address etc.</p>
<input type="text" name="t_detail" align="left" size="80" maxlength="800">
</body>
</html>
```

**i want to convert these data as design view using c# code**
[image]

***is this possible in C#.net***

**ANSWER / UPDATE**

```
byte[] results= wc.UploadValues("url",postData);
//variable results have these data = "<html>.....</html>";
```

i want the string variable values as how the html code display in the browser
This is the solution

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = results;
```

Thanks

Comment: Build an ASPX page and paste the HTML into it? It's terribly unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Are you using web forms or mvc?

Comment: Put an asp label on your page and assign your string's value into label's text.

Comment: I think you need to learn some ASP.NET first... you don't seem to know what you're doing at all...

Comment: @Emil Lundin i am asking in windows desktop applicaion

Comment: Why the HTML then? Are you converting an HTML-app to a desktop-app?`

Comment: @GOPI look at my updated answer.

Comment: i had update the post please look on it..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create HTML file from your HTML `string` variable:

```
string yourHtmlString = "<html>..."
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\YourPage.html", yourHtmlString );
```

**Update:**

If you are using [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, use this:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = yourHtmlString;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try the HTML parser called "Html Agility Pack".